# Django REST How to Hash Password Correctly

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

I'm using dj_rest_auth to authenticate my users and there is a problem with registration. After I create a user with RegisterView that dj_rest_auth gives, django creates the user without a problem but password hashing is incorrect and thus I can not login with new created user.
This is my Register View:

### **registerview.py**

```
class UserRegisterAPIView(RegisterView):
    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        # user.set_password(make_password(request.data.get('password'))) Didn't work
        user = self.perform_create(serializer)
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)

        return Response(self.get_response_data(user),
                        status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED,
                        headers=headers)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        user = serializer.save(self.request)
        create_token(self.token_model, user, serializer)
        complete_signup(self.request._request, user,
                        allauth_settings.EMAIL_VERIFICATION,
                        None)
        return user
```

EDIT: These are the same password but hashed differently(First one is dj_rest_auth's register view, second one is created in admin panel)
If I use the second password on other users, they successfully log in.

[image: dj_rest_auth]

[image: django created]

Comment: are you sure that the request payload has a password?

Comment: did you try to call `set_password` before or after creating the user ? Also you still need to call `user.save()` after `set_password`

Comment: @ArakkalAbu I can't print it to the console because email verification overrides what I try to print (or something like that, point is I can't see what I printed), However in other views I already used `request.data.get("something")` to create models so I guess it is working.

Comment: @JoseKilo first I call `set_password` in `perform_create` after `user=serializer.save`, it didn't work, so I tried to call in `create` method and it also didn't work then I asked in stackoverflow

Comment: Inside `perform_create`, you call `user = serializer.save(...)`, right after that I would call `user.set_password(...)` and then `user.save()`. Is that what you tried first ?

Comment: Could it be that your password field is actually `password1` ? https://github.com/jazzband/dj-rest-auth/blob/master/dj_rest_auth/registration/serializers.py#L178

Comment: @JoseKilo omg finally I solved it thanks to you, no my password field is `password` but while I looking into serializer I saw serializer has `save()` method and I wrote `set_password(...)` there and it finally worked. If you want, write this as an answer and then I will accept it.

Comment: Glad that you fixed it :)

Answer (score -1):

I think you have a typo in your `create` method.

Where you have the commented section:

```
user.set_password(make_password(request.data.get('password')))
```

It should actually be:

```
user.set_password(make_password(serializer.data.get('password')))
```

I'm not sure what the function `make_password` does there, but that should solve the problem.